# Do comparisons consume less cpu cycles than assignments

Tags: c++

I have following c++ code

```
void class::memberSetter(const type& val) {
   if (m_member == val)
      return;
   m_member = val;
}
```

I've seen this practice a lot. Does it actually make a positive difference? Or would it be more efficient (cycle-wise) to

```
void class::memberSetter(const type& val) {
   m_member = val;
}
```

What happends if this is done with POD vs non-POD?

Comment: Without knowing more about what else is happening at around the same time, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: It depends on the type. I could probably devise a type where the first is faster, and another type where the second is faster. Have you seen this for primitive types (or other types we might know without seeing a definition)?

Comment: When in doubt, prefer shorter spelling. If you're interested, profile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should ALWAYS do profiling when you want to optimize code. Optimization should be done based on facts and proven bottlenecks.
Having said that : some more specialization of your code may be in order. If a type is cheap to copy the extra if statement can result in missed branch predictions (which are expensive). So only pay for the `if` when copying is more expensive.

```
// Define some criterion for when you consider something cheap 
// enough to copy in your case.
// it is this criterion you probably have to tune based on profiling information
template<typename type_t>
constexpr bool dont_compare_criterion = (sizeof(type_t) <= sizeof(int)); 

template<typename type_t>
class some_class_t
{
public:

    void memberSetter(const type& val)
    {
        if constexpr (dont_compare_criterion<type_t>)
        {
            m_member = val;
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_member != val)
            {
                m_member = val;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    type_t m_member;
};
```

Comment: I'm ready to put money on the table that your definition of `cheap_to_copy` will end up _as-is_ in some reader's codebase. Maybe edit your answer to remove the implementation part of it?

Comment: Well that's why I kind of added the comment on "tuning", but you have a  point. I renamed `cheap_to_copy`  to  `dont_copy_criterion`. In the end engineers should still understand what they are doing (and yes I am fully aware of reality)

Comment: dont_compare_criterion  seemed an even more appropiate name